# Tomcat on Windows, starting/stopping service

Tags: tomcat

The Tomcat Windows Service How-To guide lists some commands to run/stop/etc the service from the command line.  For example:

```
Tomcat7 //ss// (with whatever parameters)
```

Is there any practical difference to just using Windows NET START and NET STOP or Powershell Start-Service and Stop-Service?  Is it "better" to use the Tomcat commands?  I.e. if I use NET STOP, is there any possibility that Tomcat won't clean itself up properly, or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

I never experienced any problem stopping it like any other services versus using the Tomcat helper program.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it "better" to use the Tomcat commands?

They are equivalent: Any Windows executable that stops a service eventually calls the [`ControlService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-controlservice) Windows API function with the `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` parameter.

The Tomcat service control executable is actually called [Procrun](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html). It does have the nice `--StopTimeout` parameter that can wait for the service to terminate. Depending on the applications your Tomcat instance runs, this parameter may be useful in automation scripts. (I use this parameter in [Apache Tomcat Setup](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/ApacheTomcatSetup) to wait for the service to stop during upgrades.)